# How to display the data in a 'form' to a new webpage with tables for the respective form data?

Tags: html, forms

I have designed a form page with some user fields...the data collected on the form can be mailed to a website or an email id...but I dunno how to display the data on another web-page that I have created(in offline mode currently).

Comment: I am sure the community can help you with this. But I think most people will want to see some work to get a better idea of problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

remote file `welcome.php`

```
<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
<?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a webpage as a .php file, and this can be mostly html with some php included in it.

This way you can use post or get from your form submit, and recieve the information on another page and do something with it.

Form submission: http://w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Post: http://w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Get: http://w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

With the information given this will point you in the right direction, and might be a useful learning resource, if you have any problems after looking through the information, edit in you're attempt and I'll help some more.